# Какие есть функции Win32 API для поиска файлов в папке по маске?

Tags: winapi

Какие есть функции Win32 API для поиска файлов в папке по маске?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) допускает использование маски

> Searches a directory for a file or subdirectory with a name that matches a specific name (**or partial name if wildcards are used**).

Answer (score 0):

[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/FindFirstFileEx, [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). С лева в колонке полный набор функций.